# What are these wooden dice with X's and O's on 2 sides?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I have a handful of dices like this but I do not have an idea what should I do with them. Could you help me with the name of the game, or with the rules?

Faces on the dice are, 1 side with an X, 1 side wit an O having a small dot and 4 sides are blank.

[image: dices]

Comment: I see what appears to be 3 different faces on the dice. What frequency does each of those faces appear?

Comment: All dice have a face with and X and an O with a small dot in them. These are on the opposite side of the dices, all other face are empty

Comment: Almost certainly some proprietary version/variant of Noughts and Crosses (Tic-Tac-Toe); does it matter exactly what the rules were?

Comment: My first instinct is that they're parts of a wooden Tic-Tac-Toe board (something like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bigjigs-Toys-Noughts-Crosses-Children/dp/B00ZI4IP8W), but the dots are confusing me. Also the number of dice would imply a 5x5 board instead of a 3x3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The game is [Quixo](http://en.gigamic.com/game/quixo); here are the [rules](http://www.foxmind.co.il/uploads/70213732698722edfaf.pdf). The only game component you're missing is a 5x5 board to put them in, and the game should be playable without that.

Comment: Notably, the amount of dice in the picture provided matches the amount of dice needed for Quixo.